# Czech dictionary in WinEdt 10.3

Tags: winedt, dictionaries

How do I both: install and enable the Czech Dictionary in WinEdt 10.3 ?

Total Commander:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered posting this query to winedt.org?

Comment: Yes but they referred me to WInEdt Help which is difficult for me to use.

Comment: Did you download the [InstallDict](http://www.winedt.org/macros.html) macro from WinEdt.org?

Comment: I have now that Macro. From WHERE do I download the Czech Dictionary ?

Comment: @Bernard OMG, it WORKS !

Comment: So you found the Czech dictionary on another page of the same site?

Comment: @Bernard Yes I did. Can you explain to me yet, **where** the macro InstallDict saves the file cz.dic ? When I moved away that file cz.dic, the dictionary still works, so it must be saved somewhere. But the macro is a bit too complicated for me to understand where it saves it.

Comment: @Bernard But I cannot find the file `cz.dic` anywhere in the directory where I have installed `WinEdt` .

Comment: For me, dictionaries were installed in `C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Dict`. You should check in your user directory.

Comment: @Bernard Great, for me too. But Windows Total Commander doesn't find this file for some reasons. Perhaps `\AppData` is not searched through. Why ?

Comment: It might be a hidden directory. Can't you ask to show hidden directories?

Comment: @Bernard Please, see my edit. That is the heading of my Total Commander. Where do you think can I find `show hidden directories` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111774/discussion-between-bernard-and-user2925716).

Comment: @Bernard I have tried Advanced Attributes Hidden but it doesn't work. `Hidden` is already checked. When I type explicitely `AppData`a new window openes.